Locust 2.x is hatching rate is slowing down as the the of users increases
We run a loadtest with 119 tasks and weights ranging from 600000 to 2000. Average response time for the requests ranges from 500ms up to 3s.
Our test infrastructure has 100VMs with 32 cores. We run 3200 workers. The tests use 500k users with 500 hatch rate.
When we run the test on locust 1.2.3 the master's UI stops responding after 50k users, but the workers keep spawning users until we reach the desired RPS.
When we run the test on latest version(2.31.6) first 10k users are spawned in seconds, but after that locust hatches 500 users at each 3-5 seconds and the interval increases as the number of users increases. After 20-30k users, it spawns 500 users after 20 seconds. When we ran on locust 2.26.0, locust stopped spawning users after 5k.
Could there be a problem with our test? Do you know any tweaks we can do on locust 2 to regain the hatch rate?

I think locust should not have any issues with high weights any more, but I'd start by normalizing your weights so that the smallest weight is 1 or around there. Any warnings in the logs?

I will normalize the weights and give it try. I do not remember any warnings in logs. I will come with master’s and worker’s logs after the try.

If that doesnt help, post as much of your locustfile as you can.
